# Class Springer-SVJour Error: No valid journal specified in option list

Tags: document-classes, class-options

I am trying to submit an article to the EPJ plus but I got the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `leer.eps' already exists on the system.
Not generating it from this source.
(c:/TeXLive/texmf-local/tex/latex/aries/svjour.cls
Document Class: svjour 2003/04/15
LaTeX document class for Springer journals - version 1.11
Class Springer-SVJour Warning: Specified option or subpackage "epj" not
found -
on input line 92.
! Class Springer-SVJour Error: No valid journal specified in option list.
```

My code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{leer.eps}
gsave
72 31 moveto
72 342 lineto
601 342 lineto
601 31 lineto
72 31 lineto
showpage
grestore
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[epj]{svjour}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb}
\begin{document}
TEXT
\edn{document}
```

What can I do to eliminate the error?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: and the part  till `\end{document}`?

Comment: @T.Bakkyaraj I rejected your [edit suggest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/170660) because what you add is an answer to the question. Therefore, please post an answer!